# dynamic table name without using cursors

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I want to use dynamic table name within a for loop. I understand that there are solutions to this problems by using cursors. But I was wondering if there is a solution without cursor as my current code has generic for loop (implicit cursors) and I wanted to know if I can retain it the same way without going for explicit cursors.

What works for me right now is:

```
BEGIN 
for itr in (select var1,var2,var3,var4 from schedule_table)
loop
--work using itr.var1, itr.var2, itr.var3, itr.var4 
end loop
END
```

and I want to know if there was anyway I can use the same kind of for loop but pass table name to it dynamically. I looked into execute immediate dynamic sql options, but I don't think I would be able to use it within for loop. I just thought of checking this here before I went about redesigning the entire procedure to work with explicit cursors (not a big fan as I fear performance compared to implicit).

Thank You.

Comment: "fear" is no substitute for a benchmark. Given that you are executing in a row-by-agonizing-row mode it seems likely the overhead of managing an explicit cursor will be minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to `BULK COLLECT INTO` a collection and the loop through that:

**Oracle 12c**

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_rec IS RECORD( fname VARCHAR2(100), lname VARCHAR2(100) );
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t_rec;
  t t_tab;
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(128) := 'HR.EMPLOYEES';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ' || v_table_name
    BULK COLLECT INTO t;

  FOR i IN 1 .. t.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( t(i).fname || ' ' || t(i).lname );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Note: In Oracle 10/11 you will need to create the collection type in the SQL scope. In Oracle 12, you can declare it in the PL/SQL scope.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think this dynamic sql solution would be faster than using explicit cursors? To give you an idea of the kind of data we are dealing with, its a table with 3000 rows and 100 columns (all on varchar2 (10 to 400 bytes) which need to be read row by row and computed based on their data values.

Comment: A table of that size will eat up a large chunk of session memory. The impact of that could be serious, depending on your resource allocations. Using an explicit cursor with LIMIT clause would allow you better control of memory usage.